# What does linker meaning?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I am learning how to write an operating system by using Rust. I am trying to config my target system, (Does the target system means the operating system I want to create?),and I added
"linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
"linker": "rust-lld",
to my x86_64-os.json file.

The tutorial said "Instead of using the platform’s default linker (which might not support Linux targets), we use the cross platform LLD linker that is shipped with Rust for linking our kernel."

I still don't understand what linker meaning. What is the function of the linker and who and whom does it connect.

```
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the function of the linker and who and whom does it connect.

The linker is used to link several object files together. When you compile code, the compiler creates a platform specific object file (.exe for Windows, .elf for Linux, etc). The compiler will often transparently call the linker with the resulting object files. You often don't actually need to call it manually.

For example, if you call an undefined function in a C source file, the compiler knows that it might be defined later when the linker finds the actual definition. The compiler only requires an header declaration for that function. The compiler doesn't throw any error but, instead, leaves an unresolved `call` instruction and keeps the unresolved symbol in the object file. When the linker is called, it will look at the unresolved symbols and will attempt to find them in other object files. The linker will combine all the object files into one final executable and make sure to patch the `call` instruction depending on where the actual definition of the symbol is found in the final executable.

From the perspective of the function being called, the object file where the function is really defined will also keep a symbol for that function. The linker can thus find that both symbols correspond and make sure that the caller jumps at the right address to get there.